# (node.js) How to get cookies from remote server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, curl, cookies

In PHP, getting cookies sent from a remote server is simply a matter of using cURL with some cookie handling option enabled.

If I was to treat my server as a client making requests to a remote server, I was wondering how this might be done in node.js? Would my server/app even be receiving these cookies? If so, how can I get the name and values of these cookies?

I've tried using the following node.js modules to no avail:

1. request (??? not part of functionality?)
2. tough-cookie (not part of functionality)
3. client-http (I get an empty array)
4. node-curl (I get an empty array)

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `http` module that comes with `Node.js`

```
var http = require('http');

http.get('http://www.google.ca', function(res) {
    console.log(res.headers['set-cookie']);
});
```

will give you all the cookies that `google.ca` would try to set on you when you visit.

Comment: So this approach seems to work fine for some websites (e.g. google.com, as you provided in this example), however with my particular website I'm getting a response of 'undefined'. Any idea what this could mean? I know for a fact that this website has client-side cookies since I can see them with my FireBug/inspector.

Comment: The cookies might be getting set somewhere else in some route somewhere, make sure you're using it on the right thing, what website exactly are you using?

Comment: @youngrrrr nope. I opened that site and no cookies were set.

Comment: @youngrrrr Agree'd, neither do I have the `_supreme_session` cookie

Comment: @youngrrrr Not sure man you're going to have to figure out where that is being set, try clearing your cookies and visiting the home page, see if it shows back up

Comment: @Datsik you were right, I wasn't looking at the correct link. found it now - thanks!